# Network computers DO show up but can't browse them - Windows 11 & 10

Tags: networking, network-shares

I have a pretty weird situation where I can see all my computers on the network list, but as soon as I click on any of them (except the host itself), I get the 0x80070035 error. I have a PC running on Windows 11, a laptop running on Windows 11, and another laptop running on Windows 10. This happens on all of them exactly the same.

Tried ALL of the long list of suggestions in this [article](https://windowsreport.com/0x80070035-internal-network/): and nothing worked.

Very much frustrated, so any help is deeply appreciated!

Update: I was just able to confirm that the issue seems to be specific to Windows 11, since I added another Windows 10 machine and it connected fine with the other Windows 10 machine, but all ping requests from Windows 10 to 11 machines and vice versa get timed out.

Really strange! Still, any workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you shared any resources on them like a printer or a folder?

Comment: Windows 11 is months away from release. Have you put your issue into the Feedback Hub?  I have one test Windows 11 Pro machine and it browses my other machines just fine.

Comment: @user1292580 Yes, I have a shared printer and another shared scanner.

Comment: @John I'll do, but  the other laptop is running Windows 10 and it acts the same way, although I need to test it with another Windows 10 machine to be sure.

Comment: Make sure Network Browsing, File/Print sharing, Password protected sharing are all ON. Make sure all wireless is private. That suffices for me.

Comment: @John They are all, sadly!

Answer (score 0):

The answer for anyone in the future with a similar problem: TinyWall was blocking my LAN traffic. I didn't understand it continued to block the LAN traffic even after I completely exited the program, so it took a while to realize the source of the problem. I checked the "Unblock LAN traffic", checked all the optional exceptions under Manage, Special Exception, and all is working fine now.

PS: Windows 10 machines were working fine to begin with since I didn't have TinyWall on them.